# replace an 'NOT IN' statement with a left join statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have researched this a bit and seem to find many examples that use select statements.  I don't assume this should be a factor - however, I can't get any of them to work.  Here is my query:

```
UPDATE WORK a
JOIN writer_split b ON a.work_id = b.work_id
    AND a.current_version = b.version    
SET a.status_id = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ab.work_id
    FROM (
        SELECT s.work_id
        FROM WORK w
        INNER JOIN writer_split s ON w.work_id = s.work_id
            AND s.status_id != 2
        ) ab
    ) ac ON (a.`work_id` = ac.`work_id`)
WHERE ac.`work_id` IS NULL;
```

I am receiving an error message stating

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'left outer join . . ."

To the degree that this matters, I am using this as a trigger on the `writer_split` table.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: All joins need to be written before SET

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Where you have it right now does not make sense and is the source of your error

Comment: awesome catch - thanks!  however, it now been running for 2 minutes which means its a crappy query.  I am trying the escape the performance issues I was have with `UPDATE work a JOIN writer_split b 
ON a.work_id = b.work_id  AND  a.current_version=b.version
SET a.status_id = 2
where a.work_id not in (
select ab.work_id from (select s.work_id from work w INNER JOIN writer_split s 
on w.work_id = s.work_id and s.status_id !=2) ab );`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @yanman1234 - thanks!  I was trying what i found here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic598103-146-1.aspx

Comment: I find it hard to figure out what your query is supposed to do. I might be mistaken, but it looks like you set a workstatus to 2 unless there is any version of that work that has version != 2. Apart from "null", that sounds like a complicated version of doing nothing (either a row is already 2 before the update, or you skip the update if it (=any) is not 2). To speed it up, you could remove w (you don't use that table), and maybe b (if all versions exist in both a and b) to get equivalent code - that still does nothing. This is a trigger? You update every workid although only 1 workid changed.

Comment: @Solarflare - thanks!  I am trying to simplify a query that I inherited that is terribly expensive.  the end goal in plain english is that on insert into writer_split table, update the corresponding record in the work table to a status of "2" if all of the records in the writer_split table with the same `work_id` and `version` have a status of "2" (or not "1").  My latest attempt is this but is still is not working `UPDATE work a
JOIN writer_split b
ON a.work_id = b.work_id
SET a.`status_id` = 2
WHERE a.work_id = b.work_id AND b.`status_id` != 1 AND a.current_version = b.version`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to update multiple records from work as [Solarflare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6248528/solarflare) already mentioned. if your writer_split and work tables have huge data then the update might really take a while to finish. If this is inside the trigger of writer_split table shouldn't you be updating the work table based only on the work_id of writer_split that is being inserted or updated? If so you can just do .WHERE a.work_id = new.work_id AND b.status_id != 1 AND a.current_version = new.version without joining the writer_table.

Comment: @Learning - thank you.  That's helpful and getting close.  the remaining challenge is that the is a one writer_split to many work relationship so work status should only be set to 2 if no writer_splits with a matching ID = 1